# Loop through all list items in an unordered list in robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Hi i am trying to loop through an ul and click on all li.
How would i go about this in robotframework?

Help is welcome!

the html is as follows:

```
<ul class="list" tabindex="-1" id="thelist">
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
  <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

code:

```
  @{elements}=    Get WebElements    xpath://*[@id="thelist"]/div[1]/ul
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        click element    ${element}
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already at the `<ul>` level (and there is no `<div>`), so your code can be:

```
@{elements}=    Get WebElements    xpath://ul[@id="thelist"]/li
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
    click element    ${element}
END
```